# How to override wordpress dashboard for users

Tags: wordpress

I wanted to know if it is possible to **completly** override wordpress user dashboard.
I want to delete the upper bar when loging in ("the grey bar at the top"), and only take user to the original dashboard when they press "create post"(Ill create a button for that").
Another functionality that I want to achieve is to "pull" notifications from original dashboard but displaying them in a "facebook like" notification icons.
Im not expecting anyone to tell me exactly how do it, just direct me to the files of wordpress that are responsible for this functionalities or maybe show me some guides.

10X [=

Answer (score 0):

For creating posts from anywhere you can use [wp_insert_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)

Here's a tutorial on how to remove the admin bar: http://yoast.com/disable-wp-admin-bar/